# MySQL, InnoDB: two-column unique constraint with one column in parent table

Tags: mysql, key, constraints, composite

In a child table, I need to enforce a unique constraint with a composite key where one of the two columns is in the parent table.

The situation is that in my application users can have multiple accounts of different types. One of these types represents an account from a foreign source that has its own id (foreign_account_id), the others are internal and only have the account_id primary key. Now, different users can be connected to the same account from the foreign source, but each user only once. So i need a composite unique key over users_id and foreign_account_id.
Is that possible or is there a good workaround for this (e.g. would it be good practice to just repeat the column users_id in the child table)?

This is the structure

accounts (parent)

```
id (primary)
users_id
description
....
```

accounts_foreign (child)

```
accounts_id (primary, fk for accounts)
foreign_account_id
info1
info2
...
```

Comment: Have you looked at using a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)? "A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct."

Comment: yep, that's what i want to do, but i can't specify it on only one of the columns because they are not unique by themselves and i'm not sure if it works when the two columns the unique index should be made of are in different tables

Comment: Missed the user part for some reason.  So how do you denote multiple users?  say I have an account `1` with users `A, B`.  Do you have 2 entries in accounts table?  if so, then how is ID unique?  It seems to me that you'd have to have the user_ID in the accounts_foreign table too; but having multiple users on an account seems problematic in the first place; so I need to understand that first.

Comment: The table design shows user_ID is a 1-1 with account.id.   I don't see how you could have multiple users on the same account.id in the first place....  or is user_Id a comma separated list using a `SET` data type? or something...

Comment: thanks. an account is user specific, so one user can have n accounts that belong only to him and no other user, thus the users_id. in the case of accounts_foreign it is like that, too, but it's a kind of generic account defined by an external source which uses foreign_account_id. in my application, it becomes a normal account for the specific user, but i want to store the original id of the external source with it. each user can have only one account referencing that specific foreign account, but other users can have one with the same foreign_account_id. hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Then wouldn't a combined unique index on accounts_ID and foreign_Account_ID serve the same purpose?  accounts_ID is 1-1 with user_ID.  this would ensure the same user isn't linked to two of the same foreign account_ids...  user A account 1 and sub accts Z,Y.  1Z, 1Y... User B with Account 2 sub P,Q.  2P, 2Q.  Try and add 1Z error because same user "A" due to same account.  try and add 2P error same account 2 same user "B"...

Comment: that wouldn't work because accounts_id is not 1-1 with users_id. every user can have multiple accounts. e.g. if a user has an account of type "blabla" and one of type "foreign", then we have two records in accounts with that user's id, one related child record in "accounts_blabla" and one in "accounts_foreign"

Comment: Only Option I see then is adding user_ID to the 2nd table, or putting a trigger that raises an error when this situations is encountered.

Comment: ok, yep i guessed so. thanks for your effort!